# Why should the default template-argument of a mem func be explicitly defined as illegal?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In [N3126](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3126.pdf) (**Warning:  very large PDF**) 14.1/9, there are two statements that make me confused:

`#1:` **"A default template-argument may be specified in a template declaration."**

`#2:` **"A default template-argument shall not be specified in the template-parameter-lists of the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class."**

`#1` means the following code is legal:

```
template <class T = int>
void f(T = T())
{}

int main()
{
    int n = f(); // equivalent to f<int>() or f(0);
    return 0;
}
```

`#2` means the following code is illegal:

```
template <class T>
struct X
{
    template <class U = T>
    void f(U a = U())
    {}
};

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
    x.f(); // illegal, though I think it should be equivalent to x.f<int>() or x.f(0)
    return 0;
}
```

I just wonder why the latter should be explicitly defined as illegal by the standard?

**What is the rationale?**

Comment: Instead of "page XXX" please say what section / paragraph it is. Page refs are unusable because different working papers will have vastly different pages and it's a PITA to scroll to a specific page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but my understanding of `#2` is that it makes the following illegal :

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

template<class T = int>
void A<T>::foo() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Many thanks. English is not my native language. I must confess I completely misread the statements.